# How can i display different profile pictures in friends_list/followers_list, i am practicing django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

My template

```
{% for follow in my_followers %}

 <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3">
    <div class="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
        <div class="row valign-wrapper">
            <div class="col s2">

                <img src="{{user.appUser_set.all.0.avatar.url}}" alt="" class="circle responsive-img">

                <!-- notice the "circle" class -->
            </div>
            <div class="col s10">
                <span class="black-text">

                    {{follow }} <br>

                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

my views

```
def followers(request):

    a = appUsers.objects.get(users=request.user)
    my_followers = a.follow_people.all()

    my_obj = appUsers.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'parsifal_users/followers.html', {'my_followers': my_followers, 'my_obj': my_obj})
```

My models:

```
class appUsers(models.Model):
    users = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_url = models.URLField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    follow_people = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='followed_by', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.users.username
```

Now how could i get display pictures of all the followers in this template any ideas or suggestions for the query?Thanks in advance!!

PS:I am a begineer ,please also suggest some good reference and some good projects so that i could practice django successfully.

Comment: Where are the images stored?I mean which field?

Comment: i think <img src={{follow.avatar.url}}> should work